# Need advice on how to coordinate Drupal installations on my site - Drupal 7

Tags: multi-sites

I'm using Drupal 7. The main website of my current site does not run on Drupal, but it has a community that does. In other words, Drupal is installed in the path `http://example.com/community`. I'm now going to be adding Ubercart. The store pages which will use this, however, will be located on the subdomain `http://store.example.com`. I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle this and am looking for both advice on what is possible and recommended.

I may soon have Drupal run the entire site from the main domain `http://www.example.com`, meaning that I'd move the current installation to that root rather than leaving it in the subdirectory `\community`. Not sure if that changes things.

As I see it, my options are:

1. Two separate installations of Drupal, two separate databases. BUT these databases would need to interact. Hard to say now what data one must be able to get from the other, but one critical thing would be that Users's register an account in Ubercart and that account info would need to be transferred over to the database for the installation running the root domain.
2. Two separate installations that share a single database.
3. A single installation that somehow covers both the root domain and the subdomain.